# Error CS1503 Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'LoginSystem.Authenticate' a 'Android.Content.Context' LoginSystem

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace LoginSystem
{
    public class OnLoginEventArgs
    {
        private string mTxtEmail;
        private string mTxtPassword;


        public string Email
        {
            get { return mTxtEmail; }
            set { mTxtEmail = value; }
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get { return mTxtPassword; }
            set { mTxtPassword = value; }
        }


        public void Dialog_Login() { }
        public void SDialog_Login(string email, string password)
        {
            this.Email = email;
            this.Password = password;

        }

        public OnLoginEventArgs(string email, string password)
        {
            this.Email = email;
            this.Password = password;
        }
    }

    public class Authenticate : DialogFragment
    {
        private EditText mTxtEmail;
        private EditText mTxtPassword;
        private Button mBtnAutenticate;
        internal int mOnLoginComplete;
        private string correo;

        public string Cedula { get; private set; }
        public string Nombre { get; private set; }
        public string Telefono { get; private set; }
        public string Celular { get; private set; }

        public event EventHandler<OnLoginEventArgs> MOnLoginComplete;
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Authenticate, container, false);
            mTxtEmail = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtEmail);
            mTxtPassword = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
              mBtnAutenticate = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAutenticate);



            mBtnAutenticate.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
            {
                if (mTxtEmail.Text.Equals("") || mTxtPassword.Text.Equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Ha dejado campos vacios", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MOnLoginComplete.Invoke(this, new OnLoginEventArgs(mTxtEmail.Text, mTxtPassword.Text));
                        this.Dismiss();

                        string strcon = "Server = sql10.freemysqlhosting.net; User = sql10179465; Password = afcm3008; Port = 3306";
                        string cadena = "select Cedula, Nombre, correo, Celular, Telefono from  sql10179465.Tbl_usuario where correo=@UserName and password =@Password";
                        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strcon);
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cadena, con);

                        con.Open();

                        MySqlCommand com;

                        com = new MySqlCommand(cadena, con)
                        {
                            CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        };
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", mTxtEmail.Text);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", mTxtPassword.Text);
                        MySqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();



                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                             FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();


                            PagPpal pagppalDialog = new PagPpal();
                            pagppalDialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");

                            **Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(PagPpal));
                            intent.PutExtra(PagPpal.MTxtCedula, Cedula);**

                            Cedula = Convert.ToString(reader["Cedula"]);

                            Nombre = Convert.ToString(reader["Nombre"]);

                            correo = Convert.ToString(reader["correo"]);

                            Celular = Convert.ToString(reader["Celular"]);

                            Telefono = Convert.ToString(reader["Telefono"]);


                            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "" , ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Error Datos ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception m)

                    {

                    }
                }


            };
            return view;
        }



    }
}
```

estoy intentando hacer esta variable para pasa a otro formulario pero me sale este erro

> ```
> Error CS1503  Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de
>   'LoginSystem.Authenticate' a 'Android.Content.Context'
>   LoginSystem en la linea
>
> Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(PagPpal));
>
> intent.PutExtra(PagPpal.MTxtCedula, Cedula);
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de llamar el `Activity` del `Fragment` con `this.Activity`, asi:

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(PagPpal));
  intent.PutExtra(PagPpal.MTxtCedula, Cedula);
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda